# Creating a new table using multiple SELECTs

Tags: mysql, database

Please see the image below:

[image]

Given the `original` table, I need to create the `derived` table in MySQL on the server.

With `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT DISTINCT...` I am able to create the `derived` table with the `Category` column, but trying in vain to create the `Category_count` column. Can you kindly point out how to solve this?

Not very comfortable with MySQL or SQL even, hence the request.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I recommend you to use a VIEW if you are going to be updating the same table, a view is like a "virtual table" doing something like:

Create View Derived as SELECT Category, COUNT(*) AS Category_count FROM original

And then, when you do a "Select * from Derived" it will show the values of the original table, with the view selection

Comment: @RicardoOrtegaMagaña, thanks! I **need** `derived` to be a _table_ , though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following if **the table does not exists**:

```
CREATE TABLE derived AS
SELECT Category, COUNT(*) AS Category_count 
FROM original 
GROUP BY Category
```

Use the following if **the table already exists** and without creating duplicate rows:

```
INSERT INTO derived (Category, Category_count)
SELECT Category, COUNT(*) AS Category_count 
FROM original o 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM derived d WHERE d.Category = o.Category)
GROUP BY Category
```

Use the following to **update the rows already exists**:

```
UPDATE derived LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Category, COUNT(*) AS Category_count 
    FROM original 
    GROUP BY Category
)x ON derived.Category = x.Category
SET derived.Category_count = x.Category_count
```

Comment: Hi Sebastian Brosch, thank you! `CREATE TABLE` works flawless. But after creating `derived` and running the `INSERT INTO`, the existing columns repeat. Any fix for that?

Comment: duplicate columns are not possible, but duplicate rows were possible. see update

Comment: Oops, I meant duplicate **rows**, not _columns_, sorry for the confusion. The `UPDATE` works too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Select  catoregy,count(id)as category_count into derived from original group by catoregy

Comment: Hi Prasanna Kumar, thanks for looking in. Sebastian Brosch's answer clicked for me.